# Taking derivative of $\log \det[x(I - y H)^{-1} + z I] \text{ w.r.t. }x, y, z$

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Let $C=x(I - y H)^{-1} + z I$ be an $n\times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix, where $H$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix. Let 
$$
f(x, y, z) = \log \det[x(I - y H)^{-1} + z I].
$$
Is there any explicit formula for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$?

If making change of variable $\rho = z/x$, then 
$$
  g(x, y, \rho) = f(x, y, x\rho) = \log \det[x(I - y H)^{-1} + x \rho I],
$$
and I could get explicit formula for $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$.

I am wondering whether we can find explicit formulas for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$, respectively, or at least two of them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$\eqalign{
P&=(I-yH)^{-1}\cr
M&=xP+zI \cr
}$$
and find the differential of the function
$$\eqalign{
  f &= {\rm log}({\rm det}(M))\cr &= {\rm tr}({\rm log}(M)) \cr\cr
 df &= M^{-T}:dM \cr
}$$
Now we need to express $dM$ in terms of {$dx,dy,dz$}
$$\eqalign{
 dM &= P\,dx + x\,dP + I\,dz  \cr
    &= P\,dx + xPHP\,dy + I\,dz  \cr
}$$
To find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ for example, substitute the $dz$ portion of $dM$ to obtain
$$\eqalign{
 df &= M^{-T}:I\,dz \cr
    &= (xP+zI)^{-T}:I\,\,dz \cr
    &= (xP+zI)^{-1}:I\,\,dz \cr
    &= {\rm tr}((xP+zI)^{-1}) \,dz \cr\cr
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} &= {\rm tr}\big((xP+zI)^{-1}\big) \cr
   &= {\rm tr}\Big((x(I-yH)^{-1}+zI)^{-1}\Big) \cr
}$$

Comment: Just a quick question, which does the semicolon ":" mean here?

Comment: The colon denotes the Frobenius product, i.e.  $A\!:\!B={\rm trace}(A^TB)$

Comment: Thank you very much! I did learn from the way you calculate matrix derivative.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that $U=x(I-y H)^{-1} + zI$ is invertible and let $f(U(x,y,z))=\log(|\det(U)|)$. Then $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}=trace (\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial t}U^{-1})$. Thus it suffices to calculate $\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial t}$ when

$t=x$: $\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial x}=(I-yH)^{-1}$

$t=y$: $\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial y}=x(I-yH)^{-1}H(I-yH)^{-1}$.

$t=z$: $\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial z}=I$.

Comment: Nice solution! I enjoy it very much although I do not know much about matrix derivative. Do you have any recommendation to learn matrix derivative? I only use "The Matrix Cookbook" as my reference.

Comment: I don't like the matrix cookbook; yet I did not find any error in it, and it is difficult for me to explain why this is a bad book. Practically, the students copy a formula without understanding where it comes from; then
they are struggling to use it properly. I studied these concepts in the Dieudonne's books but they are difficult to read. Perhaps somebody knows a not too complicated educational book about this subject.